# UIControllerView not be updated from delegate function

Tags: c#, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

I would like to update an `UIView` in an `UIViewController` from a delegate method.

There is the sketchup :
User trigger an download from `UIViewController`, download is managed by a class, when the `UploadAsyncData` is finished the download method passes the handled response to another class. This class write recieved data to an local database.

I would like to inform user throw the `UIViewController` where he is from the process progress.

What I have done from now :

- In the `UIViewController` i got an `UIView` that represent an `Overlay` with some messages on it. The `UIView` is also set into an static helper class to help reference it from the outside.
- When user press download button, the `Overlay` show up and inform user that action has been triggered.
- When action are passed to the download class, the `Overlay` text are updated to "Your download are in progress"
- When download are finished the method in the download class that handle the response update the `Overlay` text to "Download Finished, processing recieved data..."
- As recieved data is an C# object i call an SaveToDatabase method from this object.
- The SaveToDatabase method update the `Overlay` with an progress indicator.

So far, all step are correctly updating the `Overlay` message except for the `SaveToDatabase` step.
When debugging I can see that method that update `Overlay` text are being called at each step, but `UIView` text are not updated.

I can't use `InvokeOnMainThread` as the SaveToDatabase is not an `UIViewController` what I don't understand is why all step are correctly updating the UIView but the last one not.

Here is some extracted code for all this step.

**The main method**

```
public class Program:UIViewController
{
    {...}
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        AddOverlay();
    }

    public void AddOverlay()
    {
        var bounds = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
        bounds.Size = new CGSize(bounds.Size.Width, bounds.Size.Height);
        loadingOverlay = new LoadingOverlay(bounds);
        loadingOverlay.Hidden = true;

        View.Add(loadingOverlay);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(this.GetType().Name + loadingOverlay.GetHashCode());
        Helpers.LoadingOverlay = loadingOverlay;
    }

    public void DisplayOverlay(string text)
    {
        if(loadingOverlay != null){
            View.BringSubviewToFront(loadingOverlay);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(this.GetType().Name + loadingOverlay.GetHashCode());
            loadingOverlay.Hidden = false;
            loadingOverlay.SetLoadingLabel( text );
        }   
    }

    void Tablesource_OnRowSelected(object sender, eConversion5.DownloadTableSource.RowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool isReacheable = myParameters.IsReachable();
        if (isReacheable) {
            DisplayOverlay("Your download is about to start...");
            Request request = new Request(url, myParameters);
            request.CanBeSaved = false;
            request.Action = "display";
            httpCommunication.DoRequest(request);
        }
    }
}
```

**Method that handle downloadAction**

```
public class HttpCommunication
{
    {...}
    public HttpCommunication(Parametrage parameters, HttpResponseAction responseAction)
    {
        client = new XSWebClient();
        client.UploadDataCompleted += OnUploadDataCompleted;
    }

    public void DoRequest(Request JRequest)
    {
        {...}
        SendRequest();
    }

    void SendRequest()
    {
        {...}
        client.UploadDataAsync(Request.Uri, "POST", bytes);
        {...}
    }

    void OnUploadDataCompleted(object sender, UploadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Helpers.UpdateOverlayMessage("Processing recieved response...");
        {...}
        HandleResponse handler = new HandleResponse(myParameters, e.Result);
        {...}
    }
}
```

**Class that handle server response**

```
public class HttpResponseAction
{
    {...}
    public void ExecuteAction(HandleResponse handled, Request request)
    {
        {...}
        Helpers.UpdateOverlayMessage("Processing response...");
        {...}
        HandleTrainings(queryId, action, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TrainingContainer>>(json, Settings));
        {...}
    }

    void HandleFormation(string queryId, string action, object nestedResult)
    {
        {...}
        if (action == "display") {
            result.SaveToDatabase();
            {...}
        }
        {...}
    }

}
```

And the final step, that not update the UIView (all steps before that are correctly updating it)

```
public class TrainingContainer
{
    {...}
    public void SaveToDatabase()
    {
        if(SignList != null){
            Helpers.UpdateOverlayMessage("Updating sign list in progress, may be take a while...");
            int updated = 0;
            int total = SignList.Count();
            if(total > 0){
                foreach (Training training in SignList) {
                    updated++;
                    float progress = (float) updated / total;
                    Helpers.UpdateProgressValue(progress); //From debbuging, i can see that this method is called, and Overlay object is the same throw all class calls from the starting point.
                    {...}
                }
            }
        }
        {...}
    }
}
```

**The Helper class**

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static LoadingOverlay LoadingOverlay;
    {...}
    public static void UpdateOverlayMessage(string message)
    {
        if(LoadingOverlay != null){
            StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(typeof(Helpers).Name + " (called from " + stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name  + ")" + LoadingOverlay.GetHashCode());

            LoadingOverlay.SetLoadingLabel(message);
        }
    }

    public static void UpdateProgressValue(float progessValue)
    {
        if (LoadingOverlay != null) {
            StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(typeof(Helpers).Name + " (called from " + stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name + ")" + LoadingOverlay.GetHashCode());
            LoadingOverlay.UpdateProgress(progessValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit : Some traces log from the call to Helper.

```
Helpers <UpdateOverlayMessage> :Transmitting request to the server...(called from Apply) -2037862263
Helpers <UpdateOverlayMessage> :Processing recieved response...(called from Apply) -2037862263
Helpers <UpdateOverlayMessage> :Processing response...(called from Apply) -2037862263
Helpers <UpdateOverlayMessage> :Updating sign list in progress, may be take a while...(called from Apply) -2037862263
Helpers <UpdateProgressValue> (called from Apply)-2037862263
Helpers <UpdateProgressValue> (called from Apply)-2037862263
Helpers <UpdateProgressValue> (called from Apply)-2037862263
Helpers <UpdateProgressValue> (called from Apply)-2037862263
Helpers <UpdateProgressValue> (called from Apply)-2037862263
Helpers <UpdateProgressValue> (called from Apply)-2037862263
Helpers <UpdateProgressValue> (called from Apply)-2037862263
Helpers <UpdateProgressValue> (called from Apply)-2037862263
Helpers <UpdateProgressValue> (called from Apply)-2037862263
Helpers <UpdateProgressValue> (called from Apply)-2037862263
Helpers <UpdateProgressValue> (called from Apply)-2037862263
Helpers <UpdateProgressValue> (called from Apply)-2037862263
Helpers <UpdateProgressValue> (called from Apply)-2037862263
Helpers <UpdateProgressValue> (called from Apply)-2037862263
```

Update 2 :
Forgot to show Overlay class

```
public class LoadingOverlay : UIView {
        // control declarations
        UIActivityIndicatorView activitySpinner;
        UILabel loadingLabel;
        UIProgressView progressView;

        public LoadingOverlay (CGRect frame) : base (frame)
        {
            // configurable bits

            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
            Alpha = 0.55f;
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;

            nfloat labelHeight = 22;
            nfloat labelWidth = Frame.Width - 20;

            // derive the center x and y
            nfloat centerX = Frame.Width / 2;
            nfloat centerY = Frame.Height / 2;

            // create the activity spinner, center it horizontall and put it 5 points above center x
            activitySpinner = new UIActivityIndicatorView(UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge);
            activitySpinner.Frame = new CGRect ( 
                centerX - (activitySpinner.Frame.Width / 2) ,
                centerY - activitySpinner.Frame.Height - 20 ,
                activitySpinner.Frame.Width,
                activitySpinner.Frame.Height);
            activitySpinner.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
            AddSubview (activitySpinner);
            activitySpinner.StartAnimating ();

            // create and configure the "Loading Data" label
            loadingLabel = new UILabel(new CGRect (
                centerX - (labelWidth / 2),
                centerY + 20 ,
                labelWidth ,
                labelHeight
            ));
            loadingLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            loadingLabel.TextColor = UIColor.White;
            loadingLabel.Text = "Wait a moment...";
            loadingLabel.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
            loadingLabel.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
            AddSubview (loadingLabel);

            progressView = new UIProgressView();
            progressView.Progress = 0.0f;
            var screenParts = Frame.Width / 3;
            progressView.Frame = new CGRect(new CGPoint(screenParts,loadingLabel.Frame.Y + loadingLabel.Frame.Height + 20), new CGSize(screenParts,40));
            progressView.Hidden = true;

            AddSubview(progressView);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fades out the control and then removes it from the super view
        /// </summary>
        public void Hide ()
        {
            progressView.Progress = 0.0f;
            InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                UIView.Animate(
                    0.5, // duration
                    () => { Alpha = 0; },
                    () => { RemoveFromSuperview(); }
                );
            });
        }

        public void SetLoadingLabel(String text)
        {
            InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                loadingLabel.Text = text;
            });
        }

        public void UpdateProgress(float progressValue){
            if(progressView.Hidden){
                progressView.Hidden = false;
            }
            if(progressValue > 1){
                progressValue = 1;
            }
            InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                progressView.SetProgress(progressValue, true);
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure it's running on Main thread when you updating the UI. The InvokeOnMainThread method is defined on NSObject so make Helper class inherited from NSObject. So the Helper class could be improved like:

```
     public sealed class Helpers:NSObject
     {
         public LoadingOverlay LoadingOverlay;

         private static readonly Helpers instance = new Helpers(); 
         private Helpers(){} 
         public static Helpers Instance 
         { 
            get  
            { 
                return instance;  
            } 
         }

         public void UpdateOverlayMessage(string message)
         {
            InvokeOnMainThread ( () => {
                if(LoadingOverlay != null){
                    StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(typeof(Helpers).Name + " (called from " + stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name  + ")" + LoadingOverlay.GetHashCode());

                    LoadingOverlay.SetLoadingLabel(message);
                }
            });
         }
         //So does the method "UpdateProgressValue".
     }
```

In main method:

```
Helpers.Instance.LoadingOverlay = loadingOverlay;
```

When updating UI:

```
Helpers.Instance.UpdateOverlayMessage("...");
```

Comment: I have to change class type, Static class cannot derive from Object. So i need to rethink the class model, i would like to avoid pattern that can make strong reference between object as i got already memory problems with my App.

Comment: Ahh, since static class cannot inherit from NSObject, you could use Singleton pattern to do this. I am going to update it in my answer.

Comment: With this update, Overlay stop updating from DoRequest

Comment: Make a breakpoint on "LoadingOverlay.SetLoadingLabel(message);" to check if it's be called or not, and if LoadingOverlay is null or not.

Comment: Thanks for your time Yun, as Console write are only calling if LoadingOverlay is not null, I can be sure that it's not when called. I add some output log to the question.

Comment: It's not null? En... It's hard for me to find out the reason now, :( . Could you check the "SetLoadingLabel" method? And if LoadingOverlay is hidden, if LoadingOverlay is the top view or not.

Comment: I can see the overlay on top of the view, the last message on it is `Transmitting request to the server...` So i think Overlay is correctly displayed on the View. SetLoadingLabel is called, if i make an breakpoint i correctly catch it. Also, if i step by step debug, text never update after the last message displayed on it.

Comment: I see you have already applied "InvokeOnMainThread" in LoadingOverlay class methods, so it's not necessary put it in the Helpers class too. Besides, it's better to include all UI related sentences into "InvokeOnMainThread", like "progressView.Hidden = false;", "progressView.Progress = 0.0f;".